# #!/usr/bin/env python breaks tab completion

Tags: python, bash, shell

I recently found this trick to start scripts without specifying the absolute path

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# PYTHON_ARGCOMPLETE_OK
```

instead of

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# PYTHON_ARGCOMPLETE_OK
```

Its handy to make the script more portable in case the installation path of python is not /usr/bin/python. We tend to have project specific tool paths... However using env breaks tab completion (argcomplete). Is there anyway to have the portability without breaking tab completion which is also very useful?

Comment: Breaks tab completion of what? Your text editor?

Comment: it seems that [`argcomplete`](https://github.com/kislyuk/argcomplete) uses `#!/usr/bin/env python` in its examples so it should work. can provide more information about your problem? e.g. what shell are you using?

Comment: good point. I missed that. Using the example in argcomplete docs it works consistently. I'm using bash v5.0, python v3.7. However when I strip down my own script to just the argparse, argcomplete sections. I have one shell where it works and another where it doesn't, the same script, Qt shell same tool versions.

Comment: In the shell that wasn't working I enabled the debugging: **export _ARC_DEBUG=1** this shows it's registered this script with another script with the same name
**<~/tmp>$ ./run.py Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/proj/abc/scripts/run.py", line 38, in <module>**
I don't know how that happened /proj is not on my PATH. /usr/bin/env doesn't seem to be the problem...

Comment: I got the full script working with /usr/bin/env python, bash v5, python v3.7. When I moved this back to our actual work environment with older OS. Bash v4.1, python v3.5 both of which are below the recommended versions for argcomplete. I see the original issue again, argcomplete does not work with /usr/bin/env but does with the absolute path. It's just a legacy problem fixed with more recent, bash, python, argcomplete...